# Search in table which contain multiple types of currencies

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have these tables

```
Currencies Table 
Columns : curn_I'd,  curn_name, curn_rate

Products Table 
Columns : pro_I'd,  pro_price, pro_currency  -- Pro_currency in Products Table come from curn_id in the Currencies table
```

This way for example I have the following case :

```
Product table's data as
    Id  Price Currency 
    1   100   2
    2   200   5
    3   300   1
    4   400   5
    5   500   4
```

This mean I have many products with different prices and  different currencies type.

How can I search for products where price between 200 and 400  dollars.

I need someway to convert all prices into dollars before query the data base then search in all products.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am given answer to consider as SQlserver ( I don't have knowledge about MYSQl, you just convert or think logic of this query)

```
--create table 
declare @currency table (id int, curn_name varchar(50) , curr_rate float )
declare @product table (id int, price float , currency int )

--insert data into table
insert into @currency values (1, 'Dollar', 67.22) , (2,'Euro' ,75.38 )
insert into @product values (1,100,2),(2,200,5), (3,300,1),(4,400,5), (5,500,4)
--select query to see data
select * from @currency
select * from @product

--This query gives you desired result
select p.Id, curn_name CurrencyName, curr_rate CurrentCurrencyRate, p.price ProductPrice,  p.price * c.curr_rate DollarPrice
from @product p -- give always alies
JOIn @currency c on p.currency = c.id

Output Result
 Id CurrencyName    CurrentCurrencyRate ProductPrice    DollarPrice
 3      Dollar          67.22               300             20166 
 1      Euro            75.38               100             7538
```

Comment: I think your answer is perfect. The first test was fine :)

Answer (score 1):

The following SQL query will join currencies and products table by mataching their currencies and will list down product id with product price in respective currencies.

```
SELECT
    p.id, p.pro_price * c.curn_rate, c.curn_id
FROM
    products p, currencies c
WHERE
    p.pro_currency = c.curn_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

The below query list all distinct products with their prices(considering currency rate is given in dollars):

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT pro.id, pro.pro_price*cur.curn_rate AS price
FROM
    products AS pro, currencies  AS cur
WHERE
    pro.pro_currency = cur.curn_id
AND
    pro.pro_price * cur.curn_rate >= 200
AND
    pro.pro_price * cur.curn_rate <=400
```

Query in ANSI format:

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT pro.Id, pro.pro_price*cur.curn_rate AS price
FROM
    products AS pro
INNER JOIN 
    currencies  AS cur
ON  pro.pro_currency = cur.curn_Id
WHERE
    pro.pro_price * cur.curn_rate >= 200
AND
    pro.pro_price * cur.curn_rate <=400
```